# Is it acceptable that the only access to a service panel is through a master bedroom closet?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, remodeling

We are planning a remodel and I have a question about the location of the breaker panel. The remodel plans would leave the panel where it is, in laundry room. I am aware that the breaker panel will need a certain amount of workspace and it will have that. The concern is that, according to our planned layout, the only access to the laundry room would be to walk through the master closet, and through a door at the back of the closet which opens into the laundry room. Currently, the only way to access the laundry room is to go outside onto our carport and go through the door. We are planning to turn the carport into a Master Bedroom, Bath, and Walk-Through closet. Does this break any codes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your story is rather twisty. Currently, the only access to the panel is through the carport. In the future, it's accessible only through the master closet. Do I have it right?

Comment: The panel is staying in the laundry room itself this whole time, correct?

Comment: (Also, good on ya' for paying attention to the 110.26(A) clear working space stuff, as it's likely the most commonly violated clause in the entire NEC)

Comment: Isherwood - Yes because the carport is becoming the Master bedroom.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel - Yes. The only thing changing is the access to the laundry room.

Comment: Over the river and through the woods?

Answer (score 1):

As long at the panel is not in a bathroom, clothes closet or on a stairway the panel would be ok with the required working space 30" width or width of the panel if wider than 30" and headroom it would be legal if accessible. I realised I did not specifically answer your question. Yes your service panel can be in a room that is accessible and yours is accessible (and not in a prohibited area).